What is the difference between "get + verb+ and "verb"?
What is the difference between two clauses below:

He was robbed yesetrday at 1 pm near my house.
He got robbed yesetrday at 1 pm near my house.


See the google ngram viewer.  Also, note that the word is yesterday.

Your example contrasts get PP and be PP, where PP is a past participle. Your title is about something different.

And your example comprises two sentences, not two mere clauses.

You mean "What is the difference between get [verb]ed and be [verb]ed?"

In Starlight 11 textbook, I saw that "get + verb" means that something happened unexpectedly. Is it true?

Not necessarily. It's usually more informal/colloquial than 'be [verb]ed'. See this explanation.

It's not that to get verbed actually "means" to be unexpectedly verbed. Idiomatically, it carries slightly different implications as regards "agent / patient" ("active" or "passive" subject), but this is hard to pin down. To my ear, I got stopped by the police last night more strongly implies speaker feels "passively aggrieved" than I was stopped... But it seems like the opposite effect in I got married in my teens, which to me implies by my own choice more strongly than I was married in my teens (perhaps forced by circumstances or relatives).

This question is similar to: It is possible to use "to get" instead of "to be" in passive voice?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. See also Can get and be be interchangeable or not? and possibly others.

YESTERDAY, you spelled it  yesetrday

Also is get cut a passive voice. You need to look for similar questions before posting a new question.

They both mean the same, but I would consider "he got robbed" as more colloquial, and I wouldn't expect to see/hear it in more formal situations
